# Unit Test Garbage Collection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

**Question**
Do unit tests automatically dispose resources via garbage collection (`System.IO.Stream` in my case) once the test(s) have completed, or are things left open/in-use, requiring the disposing of `IDisposable` objects?

**Context / Information**
I'm currently making a unit test for a file uploader which uses a `System.IO.Stream`.
I've Moq'd out the `HttpPostedFileBase` with the InputStream of the file powered by a `System.IO.MemoryStream`, which all works as expected.

I currently have (altered for brevity):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUpload()
{
  var stream = FunctionCreatingTheMemoryStream();
  try
  {
    var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    file.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
    file.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);  
    MethodThatUsesTheStream(file.Object)  
    // rest of test code with Assert
  }
  finally
  {
    stream.Dispose();
  }
}
```

The question is with the `MemoryStream` instance that is created:

```
var stream = new FunctionCreatingTheMemoryStream();
```

Is it worthwhile placing any code after this in a `try catch` and then disposing of the stream in the `finally` statement, or with it being a unit test, will the memory stream be disposed of automatically?

So is it necessary to do this, or could it simply just be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUpload()
{
   var stream = FunctionCreatingTheMemoryStream();
   var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();  

   file.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
   file.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);  
   MethodThatUsesTheStream(file.Object)
   // rest of test code with Assert
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are numerous duplicates to this question here on SO. If you don't have a very good reason not to, always call Dispose on objects implementing `IDisposable` when done with them. Since you're asking about it, I would say you don't have a good reason, so just do it.

Comment: Its possible that the mocking framework does some magic but there is no harm doing it yourself. And I believe that in general `Dispose` and `Close` are synonymous on streams so you'd only need one. And I'd then go with a `using` statement.

Comment: I dont see class which you are testing here - you have only memory stream and mock

Comment: I can't actually find a similar question @LasseV.Karlsen, hence why I asked it. If you can link an appropriate question then please do. I ask though also as I don't want to have unnecessary code in my test.

Comment: @Chris thanks. I already tried a using statement for creating the stream but it's closed when it's returned, so I suppose I could just wrap it all in a closure, but then I'm in a similar situation as wrapping everything in a try catch.

Comment: @danrichardson: A using statement is just a shorthand for what you have done there (ie declaring an element, putting its body in a try and disposing of the element in a finally). It sounds like you are not using it correctly.

Comment: @Chris I meant using statement when I said closure >_< - apologies.

Comment: MemoryStream unlike most stream do not need to be disposed or closed, as there is no file, or network to closedown.   There is no magic that makes a unit test call dispose for you.

Comment: @IanRingrose: `MemoryStream` has code in its `Dispose` method which leads me to believe that you probably should dispose it like anything else that implements `IDisposable`. Though I will agree it is probably not as necessary as ones with external resources.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek I disagree. I don't think SO needs to have SoC as a ruleset for asking questions. The question is only relevant to the way resources are collected and disposed of using IDisposable. This question is irrelevant to another language... surely?

Comment: @OndrejJanacek however, I did actually mean to put Visual Studio / MSTest, not C#, that was incorrect. MSTest would have been better suited.

Comment: @Chris, IO.Stream has the dispose method, as **some** of it's sub classes need to be disposed.   In the case of your tests, I rather have the test be more readable, then care too much about calling dispose methods when you don't need to call them.

Comment: @danrichardson It would surely be more appropriate, but still not necessary. Tags serve this purpose very well. There's always a way to format a title that it does not collide.

Comment: @IanRingrose: I didn't mean it has a dispose method so you should call it. I meant it has a dispose method with code in it. It does seem to be mainly for closing the stream but I can't help but think if MS went to the effort of putting code in there its probably because it should be called.

Comment: @Chris, if I recall correctly that code is there as  IO.Stream defines that some methods must throw an exception if it has been closed.

Comment: @IanRingrose: possibly yeah. I'd still go with the theory that its good practice to call dispose on everything disposable to be on the safe side though I think you are probably right about what that code does.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer ultimately depends on the unit testing framework you use, but in .NET, none of the three major test frameworks (MSTest, NUnit, xUnit.net) automatically dispose of things. You have to manually ask them to do so.

You could argue that when executing a test suite, the test runner in principle launches a new process, runs all the tests, and then the process exits.

For some implementations of `IDisposable`, like `MemoryStream`, that simply means that the memory is reclaimed when the process exits. However, you can't always rely on that, because some disposable types may access out-of-process resources. You could theoretically have objects holding on to memory-mapped-files, named pipes, SQL Server connections, etc. Even if the test process exits, you may leave behind such resources. They'll probably time out sooner or later (like SQL Server connections returning to the pool), but it may slow down your system.

Furthermore, some test runners are attempting very hard to be clever these days, so they reuse one or more processes to be able to run faster, changing your test suite in and out of AppDomains.

So, in the end, unless you have something like a `MemoryStream`, where you're absolutely certain that it's not a big deal to leave it behind, you should deterministically dispose of your objects in your tests.

However, if you're doing Test-Driven Development, you should adopt the [GOOS](http://amzn.to/VI81bP) attitude of **listening to your tests**. If you write *a lot* of tests that involve IDisposable objects, you should consider if you can simplify your SUT's API. It depends on what you're doing, but if you write mostly managed code, you shouldn't need `IDisposable` much, because it's a **Leaky Abstraction** that leaks that the SUT depends on unmanaged resources..

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's quite clear. Ironically it's ultimately your brilliant "Dependancy Injection in .NET" book that's put me in this situation in the first place. From a Yes/No pov, it's a "no it doesn't", so it sounds as though it's worthwhile just disposing out of good practice anyway if things can/will be left behind. I think if I was writing a single or multiple test that was very large/intensive I think it's more an issue, but in simple scenarios disposing or not disposing sounds like it becomes almost irrelevant. I'm only writing small scale managed code that is via a TDD approach

Comment: **not** via a TDD approach.

Comment: +1 for the general advice. But xUnit v2 in the last few weeks has started `Dispose`ing Theory arguments [that are `IDisposable`]

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have written a "Dustcart" class that implements IDisposable, and contains a collection of objects to dispose.    These are disposed in the opersite order to how they are added (use a stack to implement it).

Then the test code looks like.

```
[Setup]
Public void Setup()
{
    _dustcart = new Dustcart()
}

[TearDown] 
public void TearDown ()
{
  _dustcart.Dispose();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestUpload()
{
   var stream = _dustcart.DisposeOnTearDown(FunctionCreatingTheMemoryStream());
   var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();  

   file.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
   file.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);  
   MethodThatUsesTheStream(file.Object)
   // rest of test code with Assert
}
```

`DisposeOnTearDown()` is a generic method.  You could put this this in a super class that all your tests inherent from, that also includes o[bject mothers](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ObjectMother.html) for the classes you need to mock etc.

**However if you are not very careful your test code becomes harder to understand with no real benefit to the quality of the software you are testing.   The tests are there to do a job and they have to be no better than is needed to do that job.**

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with everyone that you need to dispose such objects.  You can simplify your code a bit by using "using" statements, like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestUpload()
{
  using (var stream = FunctionCreatingTheMemoryStream())
  {
    var file = new Mock<HttpPostedFileBase>();
    file.Setup(f => f.FileName).Returns("test.txt");
    file.Setup(f => f.InputStream).Returns(stream);  
    MethodThatUsesTheStream(file.Object)  
    // rest of test code with Assert
  }
}
```